# How to autopopulate a field in SugarCRM form

Tags: sugarcrm

We have not yet customized SugarCRM 6 but here's our first issue.

When we are browsing a Contact's record, under the "Activities" subpanel, we can create a new meeting by clicking on "Create Meeting".  Then, a quick form appears and the Account field (parent_name) is autopopulated with the Contact's associated Account name.

My question: how to modify that and autopopulate the parent_name with the Contact's name instead, so that the Meeting will be link to the Contact's record and not the Account's record.

Thanks !

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I believe you should be looking at /modules/Meeting/MettingFormBase.php

Copy this to custom/modules/Meeting/ of course.

Look about line 73;
        `$default_parent_type= $app_list_strings['record_type_default_key'];`
and line 83;
        `<input type="hidden" name="${prefix}parent_type" value="${default_parent_type}">`

This could be changed something like; 
        `if($_REQUEST['module'] == 'Contacts'){
$default_parent_type = 'Contacts;
}else{
'$app_list_strings['record_type_default_key'];
}`

Code is not tested but hopefully it will point you in the correct direction.