# Sugarcrm : how to auto-populate field with related fields in QUICKCREATE view?

Tags: standards, sugarcrm, autofill

**My configuration :**
Sugar Entreprise 6.5.16

**What i want to achieve :**

When creating a contact by the quickcreate view (ie by clicking on "Create" in the Contact subpanel), i want to bring back any address informations from the related account chosen.

IE : I'm in my dashlet "My Contacts" on my home, i want to edit a contact. Sugar opens the popup, and i change the Account related to the contact. I chose, ie Microsoft. So, now that this account is chosen, i want Sugar to auto-fill the contact's address fields with the related account's address information.

**What i've tested :**

I saw this one :

[How to autopopulate a field in SugarCRM form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807448/how-to-autopopulate-a-field-in-sugarcrm-form)

and johndope's blog article (which is reaaaally helpful)
http://johndopenotes.wordpress.com/2013/03/18/sugarcrm-populating-fields-using-a-relate-field/

So i've created my *SugarRoot/custom/Extension/modules/Contacts/Ext/Vardefs/sugarfield_account_name.php*

and added this :

```
$dictionary['Contacts']['fields']['account_name']['populate_list'] = array('id','name','Accounts');
$dictionary['Contacts']['fields']['account_name']['field_list'] = array('account_id','account_name','primary_address_street');
```

And then, i edited my *SugarRoot/custom/modules/Contacts/metadata/quickcreatedefs.php*
and added this :

```
array (
        'name' => 'account_name',
        'displayParams' => 
        array (
          'key' => 'billing',
          'copy' => 'primary',
          'billingKey' => 'primary',
          'additionalFields' => 
          array (
            'phone_office' => 'phone_work',
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

After a quick Rebuild and Repair, i've tested it, and nothing is happening.
I have to say that i've already done the exactly same thing for editviewdefs.php and it works...

So please, help me with this! :)

Answer (score 1):

Recommendation from https://community.sugarcrm.com/sugarcrm/topics/auto_fill_related_field_from_parent_module_to_child_module

Example for Companies. Try adapt this code for your needs.

In custom/modules//views/view.quickcreate.php
Extend ViewQuickCreate class to set the corresponding $_REQUEST variable in preDisplay.
Remember that this is used by the + at the top right as well in case you have Contracts there so check that there is a parent and that it's a Company first.

```
class ContractViewQuickcreate extends ViewQuickcreate
  function preDisplay(){
    parent::preDisplay();
    if (isset($_REQUEST['parent_id']) && $_REQUEST['parent_id'] != ''     && isset($_REQUEST['parent_type']) &&  $_REQUEST['parent_type'] == 'Companies'){
         $comp = new Company();
         $comp->retrieve($_REQUEST['parent_id']);
         //say the fields are company_id and company_name in Companies
         //and company_id_c and company_name_c in Contracts
         //assuming company is a relate field you'll need to map both
         $_REQUEST['company_id_c'] = $comp->company_id;
         $_REQUEST['company_name_c'] = $comp->company_name;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
[Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)